# Euclidean BTZ black hole dual to thermal CFT state

Tags: black-holes, ads-cft, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

I'm studying $\textbf{Holographic Derivation of Entanglement Entropy from AdS/CFT}$ by Shinsei Ryu and Tadashi Takayanagi.

I'm trying to compute the entanglement entropy in $CFT_2/AdS_3$ at finite temperature. I have calculated it in $CFT_2$ but I have issues calculating it in $AdS_3$.

My first question is, why are we considering a Euclidean BTZ black hole as a dual gravity? Isn't there any other spacetime that could create thermal states? Does someone have some intuition about this?

Secondly, I don't get how to find the geodesic length given the metric. In an other paper they use this equation as an intermediary step $$
\frac{d r}{d x}=\frac{r}{l_{A d S}^{2}} \sqrt{\left(r^{2}-r_{+}^{2}\right)\left(\frac{r^{2}}{r_{*}^{2}}-1\right)}
$$

Comment: I would have said for my first question that, we can use a black hole geometry because thanks to Hawking radiation we would have a thermal bath for our CFT states. To have an asymptotic AdS space-time we need the particular case of BTZ Black hole? Is it true? Are there any other options?